# iPhone - Create custom small view for all view controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

A custom view for displaying on tapping map pin should be created using storyboard.
It may possible to create custom view outside of View controller inside a scene. 
     But creating a single custom view should be used on all other view controllers which are using map control.

```
 How to create a custom view(width:300, height:150) on storyboard and that created view can be used on other view controller also?
```

Please advice...

Answer (score 0):

Just build UIView in XIB I guess, create base class whit accessing awakes this view from XIB and adding it as a subview.

to load view from XIB you can use UIView category (name XIB same as classname):

```
@implementation UIView (NIB)

+ (id)loadFromNIBWithName:(NSString *)aName {
    Class klass = [self class];
    NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:aName owner:self options:nil];
    for (id object in objects) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:klass]) {
            return object;
        }
    }
    [NSException raise:@"WrongNibFormat" format:@"Nib for '%@' must contain one UIView, and its class must be '%@'", aName, NSStringFromClass(klass)];
    return nil;
}

+ (UIView *)loadFromNIBWithName:(NSString *)aName frame:(CGRect)aFrame {
    UIView *v = (UIView *)[self loadFromNIBWithName:aName];
    v.frame = aFrame;
    return v;
}

+ (id)loadFromNIB {
    return [self loadFromNIBWithName:[self nibName]];
}

+ (UIView *)loadFromNIBWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame {
    UIView *v = (UIView *)[self loadFromNIB];
    v.frame = aFrame;
    return v;
}

+ (NSString*)nibName {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

@end
```

one more solution you can create `UIViewController` with your view, create custom segue to it, override `- (void)perform` method to take view from `destinationViewController` and put in on `sourceViewController.view`